# gaining access to forward declared structures

Tags: c

```
gcc 4.5.1 c89
```

I am maintaining someone's code. And they have got things really locked down in terms of not exposing the structures in the header files. They have forward declared these data structures. I can't change any of these as it will affect other parts of the application.

In our driver file I had to create a sorting routine using the insertion sort. That sorts on the number of votes. I am just sending the code snippets of the relavent pieces I had to modify.

Here is the candidate implementation file candidate.c

```
struct Candidates_t {
    int id;
    char *name;
    size_t votes;
};

int get_candidate_vote(const Candidates_t *candidates)
{
    return candidates->votes;
}
```

Here is the candidate header file candidate.h:

```
typedef struct Candidates_t Candidates_t;
int get_candidate_vote(const Candidates_t *candidate);
```

In the driver file I include the candidate.h file. I then store all the candiates that are created into the cand_data structure.

```
typedef struct Candidate_data_t {
    size_t candidate_data_id;
    Candidates_t *candidate;
    size_t votes;
} Candidate_data;

Candidate_data *cand_data[NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATES] = {0};
/* This runs in a for loop */
cand_data[i] = create_candidate_data(candidate, i);

for(j = 1; j < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATES; j++) {
    temp_cand_data = cand_data[j];
    k = j - 1;

    /* Get the votes to compare */
    vote_temp = get_candidate_vote(temp_cand_data->candidate);
    vote_cand = get_candidate_vote(cand_data[k]->candidate);

    while(k >= 0 && vote_temp < vote_cand) {
        cand_data[k + 1] = cand_data[k];
        vote_cand = get_candidate_vote(cand_data[k]->candidate);
        k = k - 1;
    }
    cand_data[k + 1] = temp_cand_data;
}
```

However, for the above sorting routine to work I had to create the getter function to get each vote to compare.

I was hoping to create more abstraction and pass the array to a sorting routine in the candidate.c file to return a sorted array. However, the candidate.c file doesn't know the structure in the driver.c file.

I am just wondering if there any way of making this work better? Or should I just leave with what I have done?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: your solution actually sounds like the correct one, if Candidates_t really needs to encapsulate its contents.

Comment: Agree with @lijie.  This is a nice clean way to do it, and you or somebody else may later find more uses for `get_candidate_vote`.  One minor change you might consider: Find the insert position in the array and use `memmove` once rather than moving the structs one at a time.

Comment: @lije. Maybe, your right. I was hopping to get other ideas. I would like to wait a bit longer, in-case someone comes up with something I hadn't thought about. @aschelper, not too sure I understand how I can use the memmove, can you give a short example. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a `candidate_data_t` structure, anyway? Aren't the `votes` and `id` members redundant with the date contained in the pointed-to `Candidate`? And why do you have to use a particular sorting algorithm?

Comment: @Karl. Well, I am just maintaining someone's code who left the company, so just finishing what they started. However, by removing the candidate_data_t would cause unexpected problems with the source code, as they are other parts that use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to export a *comparison* function that compares two `Candidate`s, rather than directly export a "getter".  In `candidate.c`:

```
/* Returns 1 if `a` is greater than `b`, otherwise 0 */
int compare_candidates(const Candidates_t *a, const Candidates_t *b)
{
    return a->votes > b->votes;
}
```

Then in the driver file:

```
for(j = 1; j < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATES; j++) {
    temp_cand_data = cand_data[j];
    k = j - 1;

    while(k >= 0 && compare_candidates(cand_data[k]->candidate, temp_cand_data->candidate)) {
        cand_data[k + 1] = cand_data[k];
        k = k - 1;
    }
    cand_data[k + 1] = temp_cand_data;
}
```

Notice that the "driver" file now doesn't have to know anything about the internals of a "candidate" - it's just a generic insertion sort, and the order that they're sorted in is defined entirely by the `candidate.c` file.

As a further refinement, you should look into using the C library's built-in sorting function, `qsort()`.

Comment: Thanks, Caf, That is the sort of advice I am looking for. I can always trust in you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create `"candidate_internal.h"` that defines the struct and is shared by the source files that need it.

Comment: Yes, I had done that in one of my other solutions. I called it candidate_private.h. Thanks.